# Simultaneous eigenstates of non commuting operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In the lecture notes of Quantum Physics 2,MIT, Prof B Zwiebach shows that the for the multi-particle state
$$|\psi\rangle = \alpha\bigg[|+\rangle\otimes|-\rangle-|-\rangle\otimes|+\rangle\bigg]$$
the total spin operators $S_z^T$ , $S_x^T$, $S_y^T$ are all zero(T stands for total), now what is the reason of that? why does that happen? because the spin operators in this case have a common eigenstate with zero eigenvalue, and the spin operators do not commute for single-particle states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put two spin-1/2 systems together, the result could have total angular momentum $s=0$ or $s=1$.  In the former (called the *spin singlet*, since there's only one state with $s=0$), the composite system has no (spin) angular momentum at all, and so that state is annihilated by all of the angular momentum operators. This is the state you've written down.

> the spin operators do not commute for single-particle states.

That's true, but that doesn't mean they don't have *any* common eigenstates; it means that there is not a **basis** of common eigenstates.  Indeed this is a very simple example of non-commuting operators which nevertheless share at least one eigenstate in common.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It helped.